# What are the guidelines for declaring for the NFL Draft?

Tags: rules, nfl, collegiate, participation, draft

For the 2014 NFL Draft, a record of 98 underclassmen have declared for the draft<sub>[(1)](http://espn.go.com/nfl/draft2014/story/_/id/10318142/record-98-underclassmen-nfl-draft-pool)</sub>.

**What are the guidelines for declaring for the NFL Draft?** The NBA has a "one year rule" in that players are eligible for the NBA draft one year after attending high school<sub>[(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eligibility_for_the_NBA_draft#Current_rules)</sub>. Is there a similar rule for the NFL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NFL requires that three years pass between a player graduating from high school and declaring for the draft. While this can include a 'Redshirt' year in which a player does not play in competitive games but practices with a college team, so often players are draft eligible by their 'sophomore' year.

You can read up on the rules in full [here,](https://www.nflregionalcombines.com/Docs/Eligibility%20rules.pdf) however the three year cutoff is a bit buried in the legalese. You'll find a much more succinct summary of the eligibility guidelines as *actually applied*, given the various ease of access to things like commisioners waivers on the [relevant Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Football_League_draft#Eligibility)

Comment: @edmastermind29 That better?