# What is the lowest overall baseball draft pick that has played in a major league game?

Tags: baseball, draft

In an answer to this [question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4912/what-are-the-guidelines-for-declaring-for-the-mlb-draft?rq=1), a pro coach "justified" his publicity stunt of picking Johnny Manziel (a football player) with the 837th overall pick by saying, "No 837th pick has ever played in a major league game.

There are thirty major league teams, and I've heard of 20th round (and higher) picks making it to the majors (although this is rare). That might be somewhere in the 600's for overall picks, 750th, if someone actually made it from the 30th round?

What is the lowest overall draft pick that actually made it to the majors?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this perfectgame.org article](http://www.perfectgame.org/Articles/View.aspx?article=74), the answer is either Clay Condrey (94th round in 1996) or Travis Phelps (89th round in 1996), depending on whether the player was signed when he was drafted.

> But Piazza has nothing on Philadelphia Phillies reliever Clay Condrey. Condrey was signed in 1998 as a non-drafted free agent by the San Diego Padres (by current Boston Red Sox GM Theo Epstein, no less), but he had previously been drafted in the 94th round in 1996 out of Angelina (Texas) Junior College, though went unsigned at the time. It gives the journeyman reliever the distinction of being the lowest-round draft selection ever to reach the big leagues.
>
> Travis Phelps, an 89th round pick in 1996, and Scott Seabol, an 88th-rounder that year, are the lowest-round selections in draft history to play in the big leagues among players who signed when they were drafted. But Condrey has the record for being the lowest-round pick to reach the big leagues.

Comment: One thing I will mention is that not every team is drafting in the 94th round.  You can withdraw at anytime.